How to setup Auth0 with both a web and a native app?
I am building a web app using Next.js and a native app in Rust. I want both applications to authenticate users using Auth0.
I successfully set up authentication for the web app, which was straightforward with the help of Auth0's documentation. However, the authentication process for the native Rust app has been more challenging. I configured a local server to handle the data received from Auth0, following this guide on Authorization Code Flow with PKCE.
My approach involves allowing users to log in via their browser, which results in an access_token being issued.
The Challenge
Currently, my API (used to fetch data from the database) is hosted on the Next.js server. This setup presents an issue: the access_token obtained from the Rust app cannot be used directly to access this API. It makes sense because it was not issued for the same endpoint.
My Questions
I am trying to determine the best way to handle this architecture pattern with Auth0. Specifically:

Should I create a separate API endpoint that both the web app and native app can access?
Is there a more efficient way to handle authentication and authorization for both platforms that I might be missing?

I feel like I might be missing a critical piece in setting up this architecture. Could anyone provide guidance or suggestions on how to best implement this setup with Auth0?
Thank you in advance!

Solution Overview
I found a solution to the problem:

API Separation: I created a separate API application to handle all API-related operations.
Access for Regular Web Apps: The regular web application can access the API by obtaining an access token. This is done by executing a Client Credentials Grant exchange.
Access for Native Apps: The native app can use the Authorization Code Flow with PKCE (Proof Key for Code Exchange) to achieve the same purpose of securely accessing the API.

This approach allows both types of applications to authenticate and interact with the API in a secure and efficient manner.
Edit: Having a separate API is not necessary, but you need to include the 'audience' parameter in the request for the Authorization Code Flow with PKCE
